# Continuous function on closed unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

Take a continuous mapping $f: \bar{B^{n}} \rightarrow \bar{B^{n}}$, where $\bar{B^{n}}$ is a closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Assume that $f(x) \neq x$ for every $x \in \bar{B^{n}}$. Define another function $r$ by following the directed line segment from $f(x)$ through $x$ to its intersection with $\partial B^{n}$, and let the intersection point be $r(x)$. Is it immediately evident that $r$ is a continuous function? Is so how does it follow? Thanks.

Comment: That depends. With enough experience, it is. For the first years, it isn't.

Comment: @angryavian Yes I forgot the continuity, will edit.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your $f$ cannot exist. It contradicts Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem.

Comment: @Martin This is the first step of a proof of the fixed point theorem. One constructs this $r$, which is a retract onto the boundary, and then demonstrates a contradiction by considering the homology or homotopy groups of the ball and its boundary.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Yes this is an argument that is used in a proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem. It is assumed $f$ is as described and then it follows that $r$ is continuous which then gives rise to  a contradiction from the Negative Retract Principle. But the point is that the continuity of $r$ follows before the contradiction. So what I want to know is how the continuity of $r$ follows?

Comment: My bad. I posted an argument below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since translations are continuous, we may assume that $B^n$ is the unit ball centred at the origin. Then 
$$
r(x)=f(x)+\lambda_x\,(x-f(x)),
$$
with $\lambda_x\geq0$ such that 
$$
\|f(x)+\lambda_x\,(x-f(x))\|=1.
$$
This equality can be written as $\|f(x)+\lambda_x\,(x-f(x))\|^2=1$, and it expands to
$$
\|x-f(x)\|^2\,\lambda_x^2+2\langle f(x),x-f(x)\rangle\,\lambda_x+\|f(x)\|^2-1=0.
$$
This is quadratic in $\lambda_x$, and we want the non-negative solution, which is 
$$
\lambda_x=\frac{-\langle f(x),x-f(x)\rangle+\sqrt{\langle f(x),x-f(x)\rangle^2-\|x-f(x)\|^2(\|f(x)\|^2-1)}}{\|x-f(x)\|^2}.
$$
The term inside the square root is always non-negative and bigger than $\langle f(x),x-f(x)\rangle^2$, so $\lambda_x\geq0$.

It is clear that $\lambda_x$ depends continuously on $x$, and so $r(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful. One question to confirm something, is it clear that $\lambda_{x}$ depends continuously on $x$ simply because it is a composition and addition of continuous functions such as $f$, $\Vert \cdot \Vert$,  $\sqrt{}$, $\langle \cdot \rangle$? And then $r$ is continuous as it is the addition of continuous functions?

Comment: Exactly. And the hypothesis guarantees that the denominator is never zero.